# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0: Class.SendQuoteEmail_Controller.send: line 62, column 1

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, sfdc

My People are trying to use a custom button in order to send an Email from a VF Page. On click of send button, send method of the Controller Class is called to send an Email.

```
public PageReference send() {
    try {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleEmailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        singleEmailMsg.setTargetObjectId(emailMsg.ToIds[0]); // This line is causing the System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

        if (emailMsg.BccAddress != null && emailMsg.BccAddress != '') {
            singleEmailMsg.setBccAddresses(emailMsg.BccAddress.split(';'));
        }
```

The Constructor:

```
    public SendQuoteEmail_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    qtId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(qtId != NULL)
        qt = [SELECT Id, Name, Contact_Person__c, Contact_Person__r.Name, Contact_Person__r.Email, Opportunity__r.Id
                FROM Quote__c
                WHERE Id = :qtId];
    ownerId = [Select Id,CreatedById from Quote__c where Id=:qtId].CreatedById;
    emailMsg = new EmailMessage();
    emailMsg.Subject = 'Quote for Opportunity';

    emailMsg.ToIds = new List<Id>{qt.Contact_Person__c}; // This collection is coming out as empty in debug (emailMsg.ToIds.size() = 0)

    emailMsg.fromAddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
    emailMsg.HtmlBody = 'Please find attached the quote';
    List<Attachment> lstAttachments = [SELECT Id,Name, Body, ContentType, Bodylength 
                                        FROM Attachment 
                                        WHERE ParentId = :qt.Id 
                                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
    opp = [SELECT Id, Name, Quote_Sent__c 
             FROM Opportunity__c 
             WHERE Id = :qt.Opportunity__r.Id];
    //Ended
                                   
    }
}
```

To my surprise, even though the qt.Contact_Person__c field has a value in it, emailMsg.ToIds[0] throws an exception. Also, emailMsg.ToIds is debugged as empty. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit surprised this compiles OK. [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) is a standard object but officially it doesn't have a `toIds` field. Except you can see it used in the example at bottom of the page. Some undocumented mess. Maybe raise case with support.

What's the button like? If you have "immediate=true" or apex:actionRegion in there it might be legit not posting back whole viewstate... That `System.debug` comment is about debug from constructor or button click handler?

I've hit a subtle bug with emails few weeks ago. it seems that raw access to `ccAddresses` for example is buggy. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm said these all should be accessible and your code compiles... I had to use `setCcAddresses()` call

You already have SingleEmailMessage, maybe try explicitly setting `setTargetObjectId(contact id goes here)`?

Comment: I did solve this with setting setTargetObjectId explicitly, but it's weird how this code was running with no exception for years and today out of nowhere the list index started going out of bounds for no Data related reasons. Probably i'll get in touch with SF Dev Support, in regards with this. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Might be something they messed up in Summer release, did you go live on weekend of 11th or last weekend?